# selecting a row based on a number of column values in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with this structure:

```
id | IDs | Name | Type
 1 | 10  | A    | 1
 2 | 11  | B    | 1
 3 | 12  | C    | 2
 4 | 13  | D    | 3
```

except id nothing else is a `FOREIGN` or `PRIMARY KEY`. I want to select a row based on it's column values that are not `PRIMARY KEY`. I have tried the following syntax but it yields no results.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Name = 'A', Type = 1;
```

what am I doing wrong? What is exactly returned by a SELECT statement? I'm totally new to Data Base and I'm currently experimenting and trying to learn it. so far my search has not yield any results regarding this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `and` to add multiple conditions to your query

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE Name = 'A' 
AND Type = 1;
```